# Book with a tower or similar buried in a sea of salt

Tags: story-identification, novel

I vaguely remember a book that I read in the early 90s.  I think the cover may have been blue.  It had a sea of salt with a tower or building or city buried inside it and there were grids of letters in the book which the characters used to solve some sort of puzzle.
It's not much to go on but I would be grateful if this rings any bells for anyone.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take a minute to take our [tour] and visit the [help]. The page on [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/57310) will you give you some tips to help our experts help you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  What was the characters' goal or point of solving the puzzle?  Were they after loot, knowledge, secret technology, a way to escape...?

Comment: When you say the tower/city was buried in a sea of salt, I read that to mean the salt is a solid, either grains or rocks. Correct?

Comment: I cannot remember the motivation sorry.  I think maybe they were trying to excavate it.

Comment: Yes, the salt was solid.  I think it was like a sand desert, but a salt one instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might well be Dream Weaver by Jonathan Wylie, in case anyone else is looking for it like I was. Credit to this thread on LibraryThing: https://www.librarything.com/topic/256320

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you [edit] in any details of the book that will help the asker recognize it?

Comment: I think this might be it.  Thank you so much, I've been trying to remember this for years!